# Why doesn't a call to std::map::operator[] compile for a value type without default constructor?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Consider the following class `MyStruct`:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;

    MyStruct(int i, int j):
    x(i), y(j)
    {
    }
};
```

Note that `MyStruct` doesn't have a default destructor.

The assignment `m["AAAA"] = MyStruct(1, 1)` in the code below doesn't compile:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    map<string, MyStruct> m;
    m["AAAA"] = MyStruct(1, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Why I need default constructor for `MyStruct`? Why does the code above not compile?

Comment: The compiler generates one for you. Just like Java.

Comment: What do you believe `m["AAAA"]` does? What does your textbook or the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) say it does? Do you see why it needs a default constructor? Do you understand why your type doesn't have one?

Comment: why not include the compilation error message in your question?

Comment: @BaileyKocin the OP has defined the constructor  `MyStruct(int i, int j)`, so the default constructor is **not** created by default. And that is also what the OP observed, and is asking, why the default one is needed for the shown example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I need default constructor?

You could use the subscript operator (i.e. `[]`) of the `std::map<std::string, MyStruct>` object, `m`, in the following way:

```
auto value = m["AAAA"];
```

If the `std::map<std::string, MyStruct>` doesn't have a `MyStruct` object associated with the key `"AAAA"`, then the container will create a default constructed one and associate it to the key `"AAAA"`. For this reason, if `MyStruct` doesn't have a default constructor, then the call to the `operator[]` will not compile.

Technically, what the statement below does:

```
m["AAAA"] = MyStruct(1, 1);
```

is to return an *lvalue* (`MyStruct&`) to the `MyStruct` object the container `m` has associated to the key `"AAAA"`. If there is no such an association, the container creates a default-constructed `MyStruct` object for this association. Finally, this returned object is the target for the assignment operator.